# Python function define: A message will prompt up if missing entering an argument

Tags: python, function

In Python I defined a function. It takes in a list as a parameter. Then output the product of all numbers in that list. The code is working as the follow:

```
def multiply (ListNum):
    ''' Multiply all the items
        in the list-ListNum '''
    product = 1
    for i in ListNum:
        product *= i
    return product
```

Nonetheless, How to add a default parameter to your function, set to “None”. Update your functions so that you are given
a custom message if the user forgets to enter an argument. Like the following:

```
print(multiply())
```

Please provide a list to multiply

Need help! Thank you!

Comment: just read about if and none then apply it

Comment: That sounds like a terrible idea. I mean Python already provides `TypeError: multiply() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ListNum'` as exception message...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply a [default value](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/function.html) to the `ListNum` argument:

```
def multiply (ListNum = None):
    if ListNum is None:
        print 'You forgot something...'
```

Comment: Hi Idos, Thank you for your idea. However, my goal is to add a None value default parameter. Use the message prompt to ask users enter a list when they previously forgot to enter a argument. Then, after the user enter a list in the message such as "Please provide a list to multiply: ", the function can multiply all items in the given list. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: What's the problem? You have all the code for that already... Just check when the `ListNum` is `None` to prompt for the list again..

Comment: def multiply (ListNum = None):
    ''' Multiply all the items
        in the list-ListNum '''
    if ListNum is None:
        print('Please provide a list to add: ')
    else:
              ans = 1
              for i in ListNum:
                  ans *= i
              return ans

Comment: I did like the above code. However, the result is "Please provide a list to add: 
None" when print(multiply()).